# How to link listbox and radiobutton in matlab guide?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I am working on gui in matlab. I have one small issue with radiobutton and listlox. 
How to link selection of item in listbox and radiobutton (check or uncheck) ?
Could anyone help me please ?

I would appreciate for any help please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, I take it that you have a GUI with a listbox and a radiobutton group, and you want to update the selected option in the radiobutton group as the listbox selection is changed.

You need a callback function, that executes each time the listbox selection changes. If you created your GUI with ***Guide*** (the MATLAB GUI creating tool) it will most likely have already created this function for you. It will look something like:

```
% --- Executes on selection change in myListBox.
function myListBox_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
```

You want to put some code inside that function that gets the current state of the listbox (the selected item), and updates the radiobutton group selection accordingly. The ***get*** and ***set*** commands will be useful here.

```
contents = get(hObject,'String')   % returns listbox contents as cell array
selection = contents{get(hObject,'Value')}     % returns selected item from listbox 

% <- code here to decide which radiobutton to select ->

set(handles.targetRadiobuttonHandle,'Value',1)
```